# Updating many items on dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have created a table on dynamodb, it has 3 "sectors" the first part has workspace with its primary key, name and description. On the second part there are items of user information with its workspace information replicated from workspace sector and on the third part items of user_invitations with their workspace information replicated from workspace sector too, My doubt comes when I want to change the workspace name on its principal sector and I need to change workspace information on the others items as user or user_invitations executing that at the same time. Which is the best practice that I could follow?

I have read that I can implement a trigger and then put every item changed information on a queue in order to execute a task to change items. Is that correct?

I have only implemented the lambda to update the workspace:

```
response = table.update_item(
                    Key={
                        'PartitionKey': 'Workspace.' + params['WorkspaceID'],
                        'SortKey': "Workspace"
                    },
                    UpdateExpression="set #Attribute3 = :Attribute3, #Name = :Name",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':Attribute3': 'Workspace#' + params['Name'],
                        ':Name': params['Name'],
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeNames={
                        '#Attribute3': 'Attribute3',
                        '#Name': 'Name',
                    },
                    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
                )['Attributes']
                response.pop('Attribute3')
                code_data["code"] = "CV6JE4YN52QAO"
                status_code = 200
```

I supposed that the trigger goes after that and then goes the queue, I am running mi lambda locally with SAM, I don know how to create mi trigger and my queue with SAM in order to be tried locally.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried so far? Can you share some code illustrating your problem?

Comment: I just added some code to my post

Comment: did you try bulk update?

Comment: BatchWriteItem does not support item updates